# Laravel mix – i can't use Vue and React at the same time

Tags: webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix, vue-loader

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined – full build
```

I really tried every advice from 3 pages of google search.  So what i have:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
});
```

And

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import TestComp from './TestComp.vue';

Vue.component('test-comp', TestComp);

new Vue({
    el: '#vue'
});
```

And

```
<div id="vue">
    <test-comp></test-comp>
</div>
```

And i still getting this error. The problem is – this works fine on a new empty project. But i'm trying to implement this on a huge project with lots of decencies. Such as: `eslint`, `babel-core`, `babel-loader` and tons of react things (about 25 dependencies). So i have no idea if something of that could affect on compile process. Because it feels like `vue-loader` can't see `<template>` section in some reason.

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:574 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <TestComp> at resources/js/admin/TestComp.vue
       <Root>
```

So i'm really confused

TestComp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: 'John'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem disappear and everything works fine after i delete `mix.react()` from `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: And TestComp.vue? Does it have a template or render?

Comment: @ippi ofc it does. The problem is somewhere in webpack i guess